# Remove RE: and FW: from a CSV file then save the output as an object

Tags: python, csv

I am working with a csv file and attempting to remove "RE:" and "FW:" from a subject line so I can further summarize data on email conversations. With my current code I get the error message "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object". Any advice on how I may execute this change and then save the output as a object that I can further manipulate? I am new to python, have been searching for similar solutions, but any input at all would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
import re


f = open('examplefile.csv',"r+")

p = re.compile('([\[\(] *)?.*(RE?S?|FWD?|Fwd?|re\[\d+\]?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*)|\]+ *$', re.IGNORECASE)

data = csv.reader(f)

p.sub("",data)

for row in data:
  print (row)
```

Comment: It's better to post your examplefile.csv that helps answer your question easier.

Comment: Strings are immutable. `data` is not changed after you have just sub it. Also, can't sub a csv reader object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `data` is a `csv.reader` object, but not the actual contents of your file.  My guess is that you want to strip out the `'RE'` and `'FW'` from one field in your csv file.

If the subject line is the the 3rd column (`2` in Python) in your csv file, you could do:

```
import csv
import re

p = re.compile('([\[\(] *)?.*(RE?S?|FWD?|Fwd?|re\[\d+\]?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*)|\]+ *$', re.IGNORECASE)

with open('examplefile.csv',"r+") as f:
    f_reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in f_reader:
            subject = p.sub("", row[2]) #clean the 3rd column
            print(subject)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes that is exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the row data, not the reader object.

For example

```
p = re.compile('([\[\(] *)?.*(RE?S?|FWD?|Fwd?|re\[\d+\]?) *([-:;)\]][ :;\])-]*)|\]+ *$', re.IGNORECASE)

with open('examplefile.csv',"r+") as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
       print (p.sub("",row[0]))
```